# Detect if data changed on jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, timing

I'm pretty sure this exists, but I don't know what to search for:

I am refreshing content via JQuery's `$('#somediv').load()` and another via `$.ajax()`. I would like to catch situations where the new content is identical to the old content and slow down the refresh rate.

I can imagine how to do it for the `ajax` case - but seems like I'd have to store in memory a lot of data.

But what about `load`?

Comment: is the content something that could be appended to the current? I.e. is it similar to a list of news articles or tweets?

Comment: Let's say I want to update a div containing "Who is online". It's not appendable, but if that data doesn't change much, then I'd like to slow down the refresh rate

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `load` and `$.ajax()` functions only fetch *once*. If you are refreshing constantly, you must be using a timer or a loop. Just clear the timer and set a new interval.

```
var refreshRateMs = 5000;
timerId = setInterval("refreshPage()", refreshRateMs);

function refreshPage() {
  $("#somediv").load(); // Or other refresh code
}

// Later, you need to reduce the refresh rate (increase the interval):
clearInterval(timerId)
refreshRateMs += 1000; // Make delay 1s longer
timerId = setInterval("refreshPage()", refreshRateMs);
```

If you need to check using `.load()` that the new content is not identical to the old content before appending it, *don't use `.load()`*. `.load()` has an implicit callback function that will load it into the dom. Instead, use `$.get`:

```
$.get('page_to_load.html', function(data) {
   var newContent = $('.result').html(data);
   if newContent == $('.oldContent') { // Whatever check is necessary
       $("#somediv").append(newContent);
   }
});
```

Comment: Right... how do I detect that there's no data change?

Comment: Your question title should be "Detect if data changed on jQuery.load()." Let me update the answer.

Comment: Without checking if there is new content, the browser memory might overflow if the content to be loaded contains images

Answer (score 2):

From a performance perspective, would I be right in assuming that the answer Jasie has provided requires that the browser load the entire remote file so that it can check the contents against the locally stored variable?

A more efficient method if you're looking for efficiency might be using ajax because it can just check the header and use the last modified date. (Stuff I read here http://www.ambitionlab.com/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-using-jquery-2010-01-06)

Therefore a simple header check could be on repeat and then exit to a file reload only when modified date has changed.

I'm going to work on using this method and will post the results here when/if I get them working.

Comment: I'm mostly working with PHP data, so the contents are dynamic even when last modified remains old